# Is there a difference between RotatingFileHandler and logrotate.d + WatchedFileHandler for Python log rotation?

Tags: python, logrotate, log-rotation

Python has its own `RotatingFileHandler` which is supposed to automatically rotate log files. As part of a linux application which would need to rotate it's log file every couple of weeks/months, I am wondering if it is any different than having a config file in `logrotate.d` and using a `WatchedFileHandler` instead.

Is there any difference in how they operate? Is one method safer, more efficient, or considered superior to the other?

Comment: `logrotate.d` depends on the logger closing and reopening its file pointer on each log event. I'm not sure if the standard python file logger does that.

Comment: @tdelaney it doesn't, but there's a good alternative inside `logging`, see the bottom of my answer

Comment: I noticed you edited you question to mention `WatchedFileHandler`. Did you mean `RotatingFileHandler`?

Comment: no. `WatchedFileHandler` is used with `logrotate`. `RotatingFileHandler` takes care of rotating the logs itself, and replaces `logrotate`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**What is the intended audience of your program?**

**If you're creating a desktop application and most users can't be expected to read the logs, you should handle it for them.** Not only rotating, but also deleting old ones - you don't want to fill the poor user's hard drive!

On the other hand, if the audience is experienced UNIX sysadmins, you'll have to take a different approach.

**Sysadmins will need features you cannot possibly anticipate.** Send them by email, write them to append-only storage, you name it. For this audience, it's best if your logging is as flexible as possible. Flexible (in UNIX) means simple - so just write to a file and consider it done.

Also, **sysadmins don't want to re-learn how to do logging all over again**. Even if you want to provide this kind of feature, make sure the default is reasonable within this assumption.

Finally. tdelaney raised a important point: the standard `FileHandler` doesn't pay much attention to the file it's writing to. You should use a [WatchedFileHandler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#watchedfilehandler), which was written specifically for this purpose

Comment: That's a good argument for the `syslog` and `NTEventLog` handlers which log to the expected places. The app shouldn't have write access to  `\var\log` but can write its logs there anyway via the standard syslog calls.

Comment: Good point, it doesn't directly my question though. But I am guessing you mean advanced *nix users would expect a log rotating mechanism to be handled by logrotate, if at all?

Comment: @tdelaney `syslog` and `NTEventLog` are indeed a better choice if you want to explicitly write code for different platforms

Comment: @devhallo yes, that's my point. It's not unheard of having a daemon perform rotation, but it's inconvenient. Which aspects of your question do you feel are not addressed here?

Comment: @goncalopp your answer only outlines the way a programmer should think about logging, depending the targeted audience. It doesn't answer the question of wether to use python's `RotatingFileHandler` or the `logrotate` tool, as both could be used to accomplish the same task. I have accepted it though, since your comment makes things a bit clearer, but you might want to edit it to directly answer the question for future reference.

Comment: It's not entirely unlikely that you may want an action taken when a log is rotated (e.g. restarting `rsyslog`). I'm unsure if this is possible with the python logging framework; it is a core functionality of `logrotate`.

Answer (score 5):

RotatingFileHandler allows a log file to grow up to size N, and then immediately and automatically rotates to a new file.

logrotate.d runs once per day usually. If you want to limit a log file's size, logrotate.d is not the most helpful because it only runs periodically.

Comment: You should note that logrotate does have a size option, which will rotate a log once it reaches/exceeds a set size.. Reference site: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/logrotate-examples/

Comment: But logrotate will still only perform the rotation when it runs during its set time. So there is a lag period where the log can continue to grow. Changing logrotate to run hourly will mitigate this somewhat of course.